# event.preventDefault(); not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am firing an ajax call on a signup form wherein i am checking whether the email id entered by the user has already been used or not.
Ajax Function :

```
<script>


$( "#becomesignup" ).submit(function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'login', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
            data : {"email":$("#becomeemail").val()},
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
            success : function(response) {
                if(response == "true"){
                    $('#emailerrorbecome').slideDown();
                    $('#become-submit').prop('disabled', true);
                  event.preventDefault();
                }else{
                    $('#emailerrorbecome').slideUp();
                    $('#become-submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }
                 $('.black-screen').hide();

              },
              error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);

            }
        });
});
</script>
```

In the above ajax function, if the response is true then the email id is already been used and i need to show an error div($('#emailerrorbecome').slideUp();) and then prevent the form to get submitted. But even event.preventDefault() is not working causing the emaild id to be registered again.
Please help me with this. TIA

Comment: you should write it before `$.ajax`. Event is not `asyc` :D . Only `ajax` can be `async`

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` need to be in the event handler and not in the ajax complete/success/error block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should submit the form programatically and always preventing default behaviour in jq submit handler. E.g, using context and calling `submit()` DOM API method:

```
$("#becomesignup").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); /* prevent form submiting here */
    $.ajax({
        context: this, /* setting context for ajax callbacks*/
        url: 'login', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
        data: {
            "email": $("#becomeemail").val()
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "true") {
                $('#emailerrorbecome').slideDown();
                $('#become-submit').prop('disabled', true);  
                $('.black-screen').hide(); /* hide it here */
            } else {
                $('#emailerrorbecome').slideUp();
                $('#become-submit').prop('disabled', false);
                this.submit(); /* 'this' refers to the FORM, and calling submit() DOM native method doesn't fire again jq handler */
            }
        },
        error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);

        }
    });
});
```

For explanation of the **why**, see [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34921457/1414562)

Comment: @mplungjan: No, A.Wolff is correct as `context: this` is supplied

Comment: I like this one, as it avoids a sentinel flag. I was always hesitant to change the Ajax callback context, but I can't see a downside +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `preventDefault` to late.

Order of execution is this:

1. Event handler fires
2. HTTP request is sent
3. Event handler finishes
4. Prevent Default was not called so the default behaviour occurs
5. HTTP response is recieved
6. Success handler fires
7. Prevent Default is called … too late to have any effect

You can't wait for the HTTP response to come back before preventing the default behaviour.

You either need to *always* prevent the default behaviour and then conditionally resubmit the form with JS in the submit handler, or move the logic for when you use Ajax to perform your tests so it doesn't depend on the form submission event in the first place (e.g. run it as soon as the data has been entered and be prepared for the possibility that the form might get submitted before your JS has finished running).

Comment: Hi quetin, I tried to always  prevent the default behaviour and then resubmit the form witrh the JS in the submit hadler but when i resubmit the form it is again going back to $( "#becomesignup" ).submit(function( event ) {} and forming an infinite loop. What can i do to avoid it?

Comment: @UdayKhatry if you call DOM API `submit()`, it doesn't fire jq handler

Comment: @A.Wolff I changed the else statement to :                                                         else{
             $('#emailerrorbecome').slideUp();
             $("#becomesignup").submit();
            }. But this going to an infinite loop.

Comment: @UdayKhatry but have you tested my answer? I set context and then use `this.submit();`. Using `$("#becomesignup").submit();` you are calling same jq handler again and again, creating the infinite loop...

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried this.submit(); as well but this is giving me error : "Uncaught TypeError: this.submit is not a function" on the console.

Comment: @UdayKhatry I don't know what to say... You have to read more carefully [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34921616/1414562), i clearly explained you have to set **context** to `this` as ajax option...  If you just copy/paste some part of answer here or there without trying to understand what you are copying/pasting, what can we say?!

Comment: @A.Wolff I am really sorry, I missed that part. It is working fine now. Being a newbie gets really frustrating at times and makes you do some silly mistakes. Thanx for helping me.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry for any inconvenience. `@Uday`, no problem! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot prevent the `submit` long after the `submit` function has returned. The Ajax result occurs much later.

You can instead flag the submit (e.g. use a sentinel variable) and cancel it unless allowed. Then trigger a `submit` from code *in the Ajax callback*.

### Example:

```
var allowSubmit = false;
$( "#becomesignup" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if (!allowSubmit){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'login', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
            data : {"email":$("#becomeemail").val()},
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
            success : function(response) {
                if(response == "true"){
                    $('#emailerrorbecome').slideDown();
                    $('#become-submit').prop('disabled', true);
                  // Enable next submit to proceed
                  allowSubmit = true;
                  // And trigger a submit
                  $( "#becomesignup" ).submit();

                }else{
                    $('#emailerrorbecome').slideUp();
                    $('#become-submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }
                 $('.black-screen').hide();

              },
              error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);

            }
        });
    }
    // return false does e.preventDefault(), and true allows it to proceed
    return allowSubmit;
});
```

Comment: Note: @A. Wolff's answer does the same thing, but without a sentinel variable as it saves the context of the `form` DOM element and calls the native DOM submit (which bypasses the jQuery `submit`). Both solutions work, but I would go with his solution (I will from now on) :)

Comment: `$( "#becomesignup" ).submit();` should be `$( "#becomesignup" )[0].submit();` :)  EDIT: oh no, i see what you are doing

Comment: @A. Wolff: Not with my solution. Check the sentinel flag usage. It clears the flag before running the jQuery submit. I could have done it the other way now I have seen your method, but might as well leave this answer as an alternative :)

Comment: Ya sorry, but then you should instead call DOM API method and in else statement, or i missing some logic there

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yes, you are missing something :) It clears the flag, then fires the submit, allow it to fall though the next submit call without preventing default (and without running the ajax again). Yours is shorter/simpler, but the user needs to understand the use of the ajax `context`.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `return false` instead of eventPreventDefault.
I had been using the location.reload() as a dirty hack to refresh the page to prevent submission, but `return false` works well even without a refresh, it doesn't submit the form.